# how to disable or enable newsletter popup in magento 2 porto theme

Tags: magento-2.0

Here I am using Porto theme in magento 2. I need to disable newsletter popup. There might be a setting for it.

But I don't know where is it. Please help.

Something written in xml file as below:

```
<referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-newsletter-subscriptions-link" remove="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line written in xml is correct.

It seems you want to remove newsletter tab from my account page. So to do that I have added the same line in theme customer module file.

app/design/frontend/theme/default/Magento_Customer/layout/default.xml

Code in file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-newsletter-subscriptions-link" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```